# Querying GraphQL Microservice with API key?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-gateway, netflix-dgs, graphql-federation

I have developed two Netflix DGS GraphQL Microservices and Apollo Gateway on top of these two microservices to make them as an federated graphql.
I have a client application that is trying to query both the graphql microservices. And both microservices have a unique API key. How do we assign API key for multiple microservices either from client or Apollo server ?
When client queries for more than one microservices with API key, there is a chance of ignoring API key by server. Is there any best practices to handle API key management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apollo Gateway has `buildService` property which you can use to modify request behavior using standard callbacks like `willSendRequest`.

Using `willSendRequest` you can match service url and append API key accordingly:

```
class RequestHander extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
    willSendRequest({ request }: { request: GraphQLRequest }) {
        // if request.http.url matches url of a service which you
        // use, add api-key to headers, e.g.
        if (request.http.url === 'http://localhost:3001') {
            request.http.headers.set('api-key', <API_KEY>)
        }
    }
}

const main = () => {
    const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
        buildService: ({ url }) => new RequestHander({ url }),
        serviceList: [
            { name: 'service1', url: 'http://localhost:3001' },
            { name: 'service2', url: 'http://localhost:3002' },
        ],
    })

    const server = new ApolloServer({ gateway })

    void server.listen({ port: 3000 }).then(({ url }) => {
        logger.info(`Apollo Gateway ready at ${url}`)
    })
}

main()
```

This way you can create some map where you'll have all services with its api keys listed, and then you'll be able to match url and api key in `willSendRequest` callback in a simple way.